# Rocket-Chat Livechat bad request received

Tags: livechat, rocket.chat

I am trying to connect to my rocket-chat server by Java Stomp Websocket client. but at the begining, after receiveing "o" and "server_id : 0", I receive "msg: error, reason: Bad request" from server.

Would you please help me on this issue?

Comment: Is it related to Server ssl configuration?